# Attachment component for SPFx solution (webpart)

Tags: reactjs, attachment, spfx, office-ui-fabric

I am wondering how to create attachment component for my SPFx solution (webpart), but can't figure out.

I already made TextField component like this ->

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

const TextFieldInput = ({props, otherProps = null, onValueChange}) =>{
const handleChange = (event: any) => {
if(props.returnEvent){
onValueChange(event.target.value, event);
        }
else{
onValueChange(event.target.value);
        }
    };
return <TextField
className={props.class ? props.class : ""}
onChange={handleChange}
errorMessage={props.error ? props.error : ""}
label={props.label}
placeholder={props.placeholder ? props.placeholder : ""}
name={props.name ? props.name : ""}
value={props.value == undefined ? "" : props.value }
disabled={props.disabled == undefined ? false : props.disabled}  
required={props.required == undefined ? false : props.required}
multiline={props.multiline == undefined ? false : props.multiline}
rows={props.rows == undefined ? 0 : props.rows}
autoAdjustHeight={props.autoAdjustHeight == undefined ? false : props.autoAdjustHeight}
underlined={props.underlined == undefined ? false : props.underlined}
type={props.type == undefined ? "text" : props.type}
                {...otherProps}
/>;
};
TextFieldInput.propTypes = {
props: PropTypes.shape({
class: PropTypes.string,
error: PropTypes.string,
label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
required: PropTypes.bool,
name: PropTypes.string,
value: PropTypes.oneOfType([
PropTypes.string,
PropTypes.number
        ]),
disabled: PropTypes.bool,
placeholder: PropTypes.string,
multiline: PropTypes.bool,
rows: PropTypes.number,
autoAdjustHeight: PropTypes.bool,
underlined: PropTypes.bool,
returnEvent: PropTypes.bool,
type: PropTypes.string
      }),
otherProps: PropTypes.object,
onValueChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
export default TextFieldInput;
```

What I know, that Office UI Fabric doesn't have atttachment component
I will be grateful for any help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FilePicker](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/FilePicker/) component provided by `spfx-controls-react`. It will offer a user interface that is similar to SharePoint online and let you choose a file from various places.

Apart from this, you can also use input `type="file"`, and then customize it the way you want.

You can refer to this link for the same:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/